# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, angular8

Im new in angular i really need help and thanks in advance
Happen text error is: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined
app.ts

```
  getTask() {
    this.ticketService.getTask(this.id).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }).subscribe(task => {
      this.depositTasks = task
      task.map(items => {
        console.log(items);
        for (let i = 0; this.depositTasks.length > i; i++) {
          const item = items.payload.doc.data()
          item['$uid'] = items.payload.doc['id'];
          this.Task.push(item as Tasks)
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

[image]

Comment: can you please show us the `console.log(items )` output.

Comment: I capture and commented console.log(items ).

Comment: The problem is your items object doesn't have a property payload. That's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your code to :

```js
getTask() {
    this.ticketService
        .getTask(this.id)
        .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
        .subscribe(task => {
            task.map(items => {
                console.log(items);
                const item = items;
                item['$uid'] = items['id'];
                this.Task.push(item as Tasks);
            })
        })
}
```

Comment: it's error 'ERROR TypeError: items.data is not a function'

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access variables that not part of object, Hence ***undefined*** error.

Please try to modify your code like below,

```
getTask() {
    this.ticketService.getTask(this.id).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }).subscribe(task => {
      this.depositTasks = task;
      this.Task = [ ];
      task.forEach(items => {
        console.log(items);
        let item: any = {};
        item['$uid'] = items.id;
        this.Task.push(item as Tasks);
      });
  });
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: error to 'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'